# Need Ubuntu 18.04.1 DVD set

Tags: package-management, 18.04, livedvd

I can easily find the Live install DVD, but where are the package sets these days? I cannot seem to find a link for the DVD images beyond the base install disk.

I am building an air-gapped machine so I have to burn images with xemacs, etc. Do I now have to create my own package DVD set manually?

Comment: There are several alternatives for offline systems. Please edit your question to include security or workflow requirements that would exclude alternatives (like sneakernet). DVD sets have a downside - you don't get upgrades (like bugfixes), so the DVDs go stale quickly.

Comment: Updates are not a big issue. I'll be deleting every possible package from the existing set any way. There will be very little hair on this furball.

Comment: In the past there were always easily findable full dist DVD sets. I presume they still exist somewhere. Can someone tell me where to look?

Comment: I still cannot find DVD images for Ubuntu. However Debian does have them so I will try switching the server to Debian instead, unless someone responds with a link before I get back from dinner.

Comment: Debian worked beautifully. It had all the tools I needed and they were easily findable. Problem solved.